# Way to easily bundle JavaScript files which contain require instructions

Tags: javascript, bundle, when-js

Is there some application that can automatically bundle (and minify) JS projects that have `require('file.js')` calls in them? So that they are merged and one single file is produced.

Specifically I am talking about [when.js](https://github.com/cujojs/when), a JS library with a lot of files and dependencies. I tried several tools like node.js and npm but I am not really used to these. I am not sure if they are even able to do this. From the the [Installation](https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/master/docs/installation.md) page I thought it would be possible (also it states that there is a minified file, but there is none in the project or releases).

Comment: Assuming that you're talking about the frontend javascript, you can try with webpack: https://webpack.github.io/

It can handle script dependencies, minifcation and much more.

Comment: as @dlopez mentioned, webpack is a popular option for that task. Another alternative is browserify: http://browserify.org/

Comment: Thank you @dlopez, webpack worked fine. If you write this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use webpack for the frontend side.

https://webpack.github.io/

It will handle the `require` function to work in the browser, but it also can do some other things like transpile you ecmaescript 6, validate it with jshint, jslint... through its loaders and plugins systems.